# A generic error occurred in GDI+. PDF to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, devexpress

I published my web app on azure(paas), on local the app is working correctly but on azure when I want to generate a pdf file it gives the error

> A generic error occurred in GDI+.

[image: this is the error I am getting]

Comment: Just a vague speculation but I assume Azure services do not have a desktop and therefore no possibility to use GDI+?

Comment: Using the vendor's help channels is advisable.  [Like this one](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T143074/xtrareports-falling-on-azure-website).

Answer (score 0):

[Select PDF](https://selectpdf.com/) now offers a version of their software that can handle generating a PDF on azure app services (using an alternative rendering engine to bypass the GDI restriction.